# The definition of the Frobenius automorphism, as given by Neukirch

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

The following is a reproduction of Exercise 2 in ch. I. §9 of the English translation of J. Neukirch's $\textit{Algebraic Number Theory}$. There is only one edition.

> $\textbf{Exercise 1.}$ If $L\mid K$ is a Galois extension of algebraic number fields, and $\mathfrak{P}$ a prime ideal which is unramified over $K$ (i.e., $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{P} \cap K$ is unramified in $L$), then there is one and only one automorphism $\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}} \in G(L \mid K)$ such that
>
> $$ \varphi_{\mathfrak{P}} a \equiv a^q\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{P}) \quad \textrm{for all}\ a \in \mathcal{O},$$
>
> where $q = [\kappa(\mathfrak{P}):\kappa(\mathfrak{p})]$. It is called the $\textbf{Frobenius automorphism}$. The decomposition group $G_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is cyclic and $\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a generator of $G_{\mathfrak{P}}$.

I should explain Neukirch's somewhat idiosyncratic notation: $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{o}$ are the rings of integers of the number fields $L$ and $K$ respectively, $\kappa(\mathfrak{P}) := \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{P}$ and $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}):=\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{P} \subset \mathcal{O}$ is a prime ideal lying above the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{o}$.

My question is the following: Generally, the Frobenius automorphism is defined in terms of the order of the base field, as opposed to the degree of the extension, so should it not be:
$$q := \lvert \kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \rvert$$
as opposed to
$$ q = [\kappa(\mathfrak{P}):\kappa(\mathfrak{p})]\ ?$$

This question is a follow-up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474392/the-frobenius-automorphism-of-a-number-field-extension).

Comment: Sure it is $q = | \kappa(\mathfrak{p})|$, when $K=\Bbb{Q}$ it is the characteristic of the finite field. $ [\kappa(\mathfrak{P}):\kappa(\mathfrak{p})]$ is denoted as $f (\mathfrak{P/p})$.

Comment: You are correct this is a typo, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48759/has-anyone-found-an-error-in-an-early-version-of-neukirch